# How do I abstract a Javascript Promise and retain the .then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, callback

I have a function called `sweetAlertConfirmationMessage`. It takes a message, shows that as the text and then waits for the user to confirm or cancel the pop-up alert.

```
function sweetAlertConfirmationMessage(message) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: T('SWEETALERT_GENERAL_CONFIRMATION_TITLE'),
        text: message,
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: T('SWEETALERT_CONFIRM_BUTTON_COLOR'),
        cancelButtonColor: T('SWEETALERT_CANCEL_BUTTON_COLOR'),
        cancelButtonText: T('SWEETALERT_CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT'),
        confirmButtonText: T('SWEETALERT_CONFIRM_BUTTON_TEXT'),
    })
    .then(result => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(true);
        });
    })
    .catch(result => {
       console.log(result); 
    });
}
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
sweetAlertConfirmationMessage(T('SWEETALERT_MESSAGE_DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART'))
    .then(
        // Run code here.
    )
```

However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Here's what I have observed is happening:

1. The sweetAlertConfirmationMessage method is ran.
2. Before the promise is resolved, the code continues out of the function, into the .then(// Run code here)
3. .then is not ran, because it has no promise to act on
4. It shows the notification message and awaits user confirmation or cancelling.

The console.log(result) does not display anything.

I have researched the following subjects:

1. Async and await
2. Promises, .then and .catch
3. Promise Chaining

How can I execute this code in the desired order:

1. Show confirmation message
2. Await the Promise: true if confirm, undefined if anything else is clicked
3. Run the .then ( // Run code here )

I hope this answer was written well enough to help others in the future.

Comment: please return.... `return Swal.fire({ ...`

Comment: You just need to return the promise from your function - so add return before Swal.fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sweetAlertConfirmationMessage(message) {
    return Swal.fire({
        title: T('SWEETALERT_GENERAL_CONFIRMATION_TITLE'),
        text: message,
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: T('SWEETALERT_CONFIRM_BUTTON_COLOR'),
        cancelButtonColor: T('SWEETALERT_CANCEL_BUTTON_COLOR'),
        cancelButtonText: T('SWEETALERT_CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT'),
        confirmButtonText: T('SWEETALERT_CONFIRM_BUTTON_TEXT'),
    })
}
```

Just return the promise from your function. You can use this like this:

```
sweetAlertConfirmationMessage('msg').then(x => {})
```

Read more about Promisechaining:
https://javascript.info/promise-chaining